# Neo4j 2.0: Indexing with Labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So, I realize that I'm talking about something unreleased here, but I was hoping someone could clear up a question that I couldn't find answered in the [prerelease] docs.

Indexing with labels in 2.0: Is it a background operation? Or will the shell block to return until the index is created?

Should I be worried about indexing multiple GB of data at the end of the import, or should I just create the index initially and suffer the import penalty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j indexing in 2.0 is going to be a background operation, making the index available when it has caught up - as I understand it currently. Preparing the first milestone to play around with right now :)

Comment: I'm looking forward to this feature. It will a great addition to Neo4j!